# DataView getItemMetadata triggering multiple times for single row

Tags: slickgrid

I assume dataView.getItemMetadata [getitemmetadata](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView) would be triggered once per row but I'm seeing it triggered multiple times! Why do I see this and is it because of something I'm doing? (ex. scrolling down the grid with my mouse)

```
dataView.getItemMetadata = function (row) {// set row css here}
```

P.S. I'm using a dataview and passing that to the slickgrid element to be filled.

Comment: Since Slickgrid is using adaptive virtual scrolling, getitemmetadata is called per every row visible on viewport. When scrolling, the grid invalidates all rows within viewport which triggers getitemmedata again to new rows. There are no hidden rows rendered once and shown again when scrolling back. Each row needs to be re-rendered again. Filtering and inline editing also triggers it as long there is a change on row/s. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the info, but this doesn't help as I see the issue occurring when I simply click on a row! I see getItemMetaData being called multiple times for that single row!

Comment: I just checked again on it. it seems to be called also when you are navigating/selecting a cell. Also, my mistake, it's triggered per cell (as formatter specifically) only that the row is passed as argument.

Comment: I still see an issue, even though getItemMetaData is triggered per cell and not per row. In my case I see it triggered 27 time when I only have 14 cells(columns) in each row! So something isn't right here, unless I'm missing something crucial about how it works or something I'm doing to trigger it more times then I should?

Comment: furthermore, when I select a cell in my row, getItemMetaData gets triggers 4 times! I have no idea where the four comes from?

Comment: i think you are using `CellSelectionModel` which is causing validations  `canCellBeSelected`(slick.grid.js) that trigger `getItemMetadata` to check if a cell is selectable.